# ubuntu shell script issue

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have some simple shell scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(date)
NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
NAME = "db.$NOW.sql"
echo $NAME
LOCALPATH = "/data/mysql/$NAME"
echo $LOCALPATH
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u username -ppassword --databases dbname > $LOCALPATH
```

Error message:

```
 line 5: NAME: command not found
 line 7: LOCALPATH: command not found
```

Something am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use any whitespace when you are defining your variables.

```
NAME="db.$NOW.sql"
```

As you have it above, bash will try to execute something called `NAME` with arguments `=` and `"db.$NOW.sql"` respectively.